# How to transport animals for large distances?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I have got some animals, let's say mooshrooms, situated at more than 20000 blocks away from my home base. I would like to safely transport them to my home base (20000 blocks away), with some efficient way. What are some good ways to move animals for such a large distance?

Tried:

- Nether transport: Ghast fireball attacks and occasionally falling into lava
- Plain overworld transport: Mobs at night causes distraction; The mooshrooms also ignores me and my wheat on hand sometimes

Also I am playing on a server so using commands is not a valid solution.

Comment: Have you made any attempt to solve this yourself? Arqade works better when askers show effort to solve their own problems; we see that you have a problem you've worked on, and answerers respond to that. You also get a more specific answer that's tailored exactly to the part you're stuck, and Arqade gets a very specific question. Everybody wins!

Comment: In survival your best bet is probably a bridge or tunnel.. with enough torches on the way you won't have to worry about hostile mobs and you could always close the way behind you every now and then (and collect your torches or other things without the animals running off).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well there's 2 main ways, both are handy if in the future you want to move between the 2 points again:

- Make a railway, either in the end or nether, push your mobs into them and then travel along it to your house.
- Use boats in the overworld. If you're using newer versions you can share a boat with them, and boats are pretty fast.
- Using a lead. Simple enough, at night time just either box yourself in or just keep going. As you said, if it's multiplayer try and get a friend to protect you

Or, maybe an even easier way, is to just move your home to the mooshroom island. They're very rare and will stop hostile mobs spawning so you won't have to worry about creepers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to transport them a long distance, I would recommend going up a few blocks, and building a long track with powered rails. Simply make it small (1 Block wide) and light it up so no mobs spawn.

Answer (score 0):

I think using a track with a cart would work easily in any dimension or biome. I tried it out, but then again most of the time I play in creative. I'm not too experienced when it comes to survival because I can barely last a day. But I'm sure the track would be possible to survive on because if you use enough lights at night then mob can't spawn near it. Leads aren't the most reliable when it comes to animals because if you go to far away from the animals ( sprinting ) can cause the lead to break. If you are using lighting you could use torches, I used redstone lamps and daylight sensors. Mine is very long and if I can possibly make it through it to get to my house with an animals then any track could be possible. Though I wouldn't recommend going through desert biomes because most mobs are able to be there every night. If you do need to cross an ocean you can either make a path for your minecart over the water or use a boat because animals can ride with you. To protect myself from mobs other than endermen I made safe houses about every thousand blocks that are accesable for animals. I don't have much of a solution for travel in the nether except for making a tunnel so mobs can't attack you or getting weapons to attack mobs.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade! Please take the [tour](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/tour) and visit the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help) to learn how things work around here. While you do provide some good options, it's best to try not to repeat things that other answers have already provided. Additionally big blocks of text can be hard to read, so try breaking it up a bit into different sections for each tactic.

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways you could achieve this:

1. Build a railway or canal: This will work all the time but it's quite a hard work (as you said, 20000 block away).
2. Nether travel + the first one. This will reduce the work but it's still quite a lot (20000 / 8 = 2500 meters long rail).
3. Cheat. If cheating is allowed and you don't bother doing so, you can use hacks like BoatFly to carry animals (any mobs and players are capable) and fly them to the distance. Remember, you can only carry one mob once, and boatfly could sometimes cause instant fallen death after leaving the boat even if there's no fall at all, or even with the NoFall hack, so be careful. Another important thing, BoatFly is not fast. Also works with nether acceleration.
4. Use lead: Slow but you do not need to build a channel. Also works with nether acceleration.

Hope it helps! Correct me if I'm wrong.

Answer (score 0):

20,000 blocks? Nether roof is the most practical way.

You could use flying machines through overworld, through at that distance, they will be nearly guaranteed to glitch out eventually, plus if that's not in a straight line, you'll need to make an L turn somewhere along the way.

2,500 blocks of railway through the Nether is impractical, though doable. Probably an iceway for a boat would be more realistic, built a short distance under the Nether roof. Still, the time and effort to build the completely covered tunnel 2500 blocks long, while not excessive, is rather unpleasant.

Definitely the fastest and easiest way is to access the top of the Nether roof (there are many tutorials how to do it, e.g. like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zBa6byykeRU) ), build Nether portals near the start and end of the route, then just walk the animals the distance, using leads + whatever plant they like (like wheat) - that combination is least trouble.